# IndexOutOfRangeException when trying to access array element

Tags: c#, arrays

I can't figure out why I'm getting the out of range exception on the following piece of code. The values for `_maxRowIndex` and `_maxColIndex` are `5`, and `0` respectively. The exception is being thrown on the first time through when `row` and `col` are both equal to `0`. I don't understand why `0, 0` would be out of bounds on the array.

```
    _cells = new ToolBarButton[_maxRowIndex, _maxColIndex];
    .
    .
    .
    for (int col = 0; col <= _maxColIndex; col++) {
                    for (int row = 0; row <= _maxRowIndex;  row++)
                    {

                      if (_cells[row, col] == null)
                        {
                           PopulateCell(toolBarbutton, row, col);
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the max index to be 5, that means the array needs to be of length 6 as the first element is at index 0.

So, change:

```
_cells = new ToolBarButton[_maxRowIndex, _maxColIndex];
```

to:

```
_cells = new ToolBarButton[_maxRowIndex+1, _maxColIndex+1];
```

Comment: Or, do what Mamta suggested.  It depends on whether you want there to be 5 items in your list, or the last item to be at index 5.

Comment: I want the last index to be 5 for a total of 6 items in the list. I didn't occur to me that the declaration was for total elements, not highest index. I made the change that you suggested and it works the way I want it to now.

Answer (score 4):

Array indices start from 0 and are upto [upperbound-1]. Since your loop starts at 0, it must end at < the limit value rather than <= limit value. So, change the "<=" to "<" in the loop.  Eg:

col <= _maxColIndex

should be changed to

col < _maxColIndex

Answer (score 1):

You have <= in your for statement...

So your loop evaluates for col =0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5... 5 is out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should declare _cells as below

```
_cells = new ToolBarButton[5,1];
```

instead of

```
_cells = new ToolBarButton[5,0];
```